# Node/Express server deploy with Heroku and PM2

Tags: node.js, heroku, pm2

Attempting to add clustering ability via PM2 and deploy via my Node/Express application.

I've set up the following command:

```
pm2 start build/server/app.js -i max
```

The above works fine locally.  I'm testing the functionality on a staging environment on Heroku via Performance 1X.

[image: Heroku log]

The above shows the log for the command but attempting 1 instance rather than `max`.  It shows typical info after successfully running pm2 start however you can see app immediately crashes afterward.

Any advice or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Why try to use pm2 to try to scale within one dyno rather than scale by running _multiple dynos_? See e.g. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm planning to scale via multiple dynos and pm2.  From my understanding autoscaling via Heroku can spin up additional dynos but each dyno (Performance L in my case for production) has 8 cores.  So I can increase y throughput by adding pm2 on top on my existing infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following documentation: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/integrations/heroku/

Using a `ecosystem.config.js` with the following:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
    {
      name: `app-name`,
      script: 'build/server/app.js',
      instances: "max",
      exec_mode: "cluster",
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: "localhost"
      },
      env_development: {
        NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV
      },
      env_staging: {
        NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV
      }
    }
  ],
};
```

Then the following `package.json` script handles the deployment per the environment I am looking to deploy e.g. production:

```
"deploy:cluster:prod": "pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js --env production --deep-monitoring",
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error but I fixed it by adding

```
{
"preinstall":"npm I -g pm2",
"start":"pm2-runtime start build/server/app.js -i 1"

}
```

To my package.json file
This is advised for production environment
But running

```
pm2 start build/server/app.js -i max
```

Is for development purpose

Comment: The preinstall did the trick for me. Been using the same dependencies in many repositories with heroku without issue. First time I encounter having to add the preinstall.